# Laravel 4 Auth With Token

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I asked a question the right way to structure a project with Laravel 4. I currently am making an API (to support a mobile app) and a web app to serve as the backend.

1) What would be the best practice for this? Two installations (the web app would get data via the api (what I have done)? Using one Laravel installation with namespaces? One Laravel installation with folders?

2) I have make a custom auth driver for Laravel and got it working. In the return on login I return an API token which I need for subsequent calls. I understand that in Laravel, only the ID of the user is saved, how would I make the api token saved at well when Auth::check() passes? Some of this stuff is making me question if it is bad to use Laravel in this decoupled from the db setting because it makes Eloquent not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 separate installations - one for API and one for web (which uses this API).
Don't bother with additional cost of +-50MB of another installation - separate them!

**AUTH**
On each request I set 'Access-Token' header on client side. This token is read then on API side with `Header::get('Access-Token')`. Then I store authenticated user just for this one and only request - API should be stateless (no user data in session, require auth on each request).

Among other things I also check `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers - my API only accept `application/json` and sports responses in `application/json` format as well.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "separate them" ?

Comment: also, how do you on the web app remember the auth token for the user? I see that it doesn't store in the Auth::user() object..

Comment: **separate** - two installations, not one `vendor` folder for API/APP. On the web app I save access token as a cookie/session parameter - on the client side, not server side

Comment: So you are saying separate them which I agree with, but then why do you say not to bother with the additional cost of another installation? Do you mean not to worry about it?

Comment: I ment "do not be bothered by additional disk space required"

Comment: It is interesting to me how much I have heard both ways on this one. There doesn't seem to be a one "best way", just a style choice.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Just pick the one that fits you the best. It is nonsense to code to style that you don't like.

Comment: What would be the best way to structure the app folderwise under the same installation?

Comment: How do you store the access token on the client side?

Comment: In a Cookie, or browser's local storage. That's why HTTPS is good for.